# how to prevent print() from repeating every alternate line?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, printing, nested-lists

##### when i run this:

```
arr=[[2,3,4],[3,4,2]]

for i in arr:
    print(*i)
    print{'-----')
```

##### my output is this,

```
2 3 4
-----
4 5 6
-----
```

##### how do I get this output instead?:

```
2 3 4
4 5 6
-----
```

Comment: remove intendation of last print statement

Comment: ```print('-----')``` outside the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr=[[2,3,4],[3,4,2]]

for i in arr:
    print(*i)
print('-----')
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
arr=[[2,3,4],[3,4,2]]

for i in arr:
    print(*i)

print('-----')
```

Comment: Please see correctly, Typo here ```print{'-----')```. ```{``` instead of ```(```